# 403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource

Tags: php, html, apache, server

hello guys am having trouble from accessing images directly from link on the server, I checked the permissions for all the directories   even the images it's self has 755 permission  the webpage opens like charming but when I access the image directly like link directly it gives  403 error with no permissions to access the resource

here are some links for the images am trying to access :

https://strongestcard.com/img/offer_photo/022e9691c5ba65d23cbf27a53f83163e.jpg

https://www.strongestcard.com/img/offer_photo/12113835-2.jpg

https://www.strongestcard.com/img/offer_photo/16679.jpg

the website loads fine with no error and the images load fine on the pages but when i but the links giving me the error?

Note : htaccess file exist and working

Solution 
i had this line inside the htaccess file

RewriteRule .*.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp)$ - [F,NC]

Changed The letter F to R in [F,NC] to [R,NC]

THANKS TO Quentin .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare a simple request:

```
[ ~ ] ➜  curl -I https://strongestcard.com/img/offer_photo/022e9691c5ba65d23cbf27a53f83163e.jpg
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Tue, 21 Jan 2020 10:59:29 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

With one which specifies a referer:

```
[ ~ ] ➜  curl -I -H "Referer: http://strongestcard.com"  https://strongestcard.com/img/offer_photo/022e9691c5ba65d23cbf27a53f83163e.jpg
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 21 Jan 2020 10:59:42 GMT
Server: Apache
Upgrade: h2,h2c
Connection: Upgrade
Last-Modified: Mon, 20 Jan 2020 12:07:49 GMT
ETag: "bec0fcd-2597f6-59c9123e289a1"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 2463734
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

The images appear to have [hotlinking](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25315/hotlinking-what-is-it-and-why-shouldnt-people-do-it) protection configured.

> htaccess file exist and working

… and it is probably in there (although it could be in the main server configuration file)

Comment: can I modify my htaccess file to prevent hotlinking to the images?

Comment: @hadyalzpen — Hotlinking is **already** prevented. That's what you were complaining about.

Comment: it seems true not sure yet i'll try  to modify htaccess file  and remove this preventing if it's exist

Comment: Thank you  i'll but the solution up in the question

Answer (score -1):

This are static files, Looks like the problem is with the file read permission and not with your APP.

For start give the file read permission to everyone and see if the problem is resolved.

Comment: what am trying to do here is that am using unity to make a game but to access the images i need  the link s of images but it won't give me the permission to even read them how is that possible  with all permissions I gave?